# Java: fast Double to euro string representation

Tags: java, string, double

I needed to display a lot of currency (euro) values, which all may change while using a slider. Therefore, I created a *faster* **Double to Euro** function instead of using a number formatter (no internalization needed, runs on an android device with limited resources).

While this function is way faster than the default number formatter, it would be interesting if it could be even faster. Any creative ideas?

```
/*
 * Ugly but fast double to euro string function
 */
public static final String getEuroString(Double euro) {
    if(euro == null) {
        return "0,00 €";
    }

    final double    d_euro  = euro;
    final int       post    = Math.abs((int) Math.round((d_euro % 1) * 100));

    return ((int) d_euro) + "," + (post < 10 ? "0" + post : post) + " €";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't store money values using double, use big decimal or [joda-money.sourceforge.net](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That's more of a comment rather than an answer unless you show him how to do it using BigDecimal or Joda Money.

Comment: Also, that would probably be slower.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: no comparisons or other operations are done with these Double values. They are even correctly rounded (parsed from a json request)

Answer (score 0):

You need to round your result in case you gave rounding or representation error.

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(print(70e12));
    System.out.println(print(70e12 + 0.01));
}

public static String print(double euro) {
    long eurocents = Math.round(euro * 100);
    String centsStr = Long.toString(100 + eurocents%100).substring(1);
    return eurocents / 100 + "," + centsStr + " €";
}
```

prints on https://ideone.com/NAonp0

```
70000000000000,00 €
70000000000000,01 €
```

Using this approach you can store 70 trillion euros without error.

Comment: I'm confused. The method `Integer.valueOf` returns a Integer (parsed from a String), so `substring(1)` would be called on a Integer, right?

Comment: Code is uncompilable

Comment: @Markus you are right. It should have been toString to get a String.

Comment: @PeterLawrey nope. Still uncompilable: eurocents - is a `long`. But Integer.toString accepts only `int`

Comment: Doesn't work: for 70 trillion - it returns `7000000000004400 €`

Comment: @turbanoff thank you for your feedback.  I have tested it now by actually running it, so it produces the expected result.